# How can a Peasant have several EVO2 heros?

Tags: castle-clash

While fighting in the Arena earlier, I noticed an icon I don't ever remember seeing before:

[image: unknown title in Arena]

Since the other player had decent army of heros with several EVO2 heroes, I thought it might be something very powerful (they were ranked around 2000 in the Arena) and looked in [the wiki](http://castle-clash.wikia.com/wiki/Nobility), just to realize it's the **first title**, Peasant!!

How can a user build such a strong hero army and still not gain enough might to level up the title?

Is this a bug in the game, or someone hacking it? Or can this be done in legit ways?

<sub><sup>P.S.

I took the screenshot bit late, being shocked... there were other heros who died during the fight.</sup></sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the arena update a few months ago there have been "AI teams" in arena sometimes. You can tell because they all have the following traits:

1. the username "Guard".
2. a random selection of double evo heroes.
3. the heroes are always below level 200 (most double evo teams from a normal player will have all level 200 heroes).
4. they have the nobility rank of Peasant.

I do not know why there are AI teams, or how often you will face them. I seem to face them more frequently after the weekly reset, so it probably has something to do with that.

Comment: Thanks, first time I hear about those "AI teams". While it makes sense, do you have any source for that? I did notice something similar in the Labyrinth, where many encounters are against teams with "cropped" levels, i.e. level of all heros is 100 while it's obvious the real level is higher. I assumed they take actual teams of real players, and just crop the level. And they appeared (along with the Labyrinth itself) around the same time as that Arena update. (With the weekly reset)

Comment: Found [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/CastleClash/comments/6yii6p/how_is_this_person_in_guard_might_rank_with_all/). While not official confirmation, looks like you're correct.